# Declaring global NSString with static keyword

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, static, nsstring

In Objective-C, is there any difference in declaring a global const NSString with and without static keyword? If it is global, does keyword static add any value?

```
static NSString *const kSiteURL    = @“https://www.google.com”;
```

vs

```
NSString *const kSiteURL           = @“https://www.google.com”;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as in C and C++:

- With `static` the variable is not visible outside of the implementation file.
- Without `static` the variable is visible from anywhere in the executable.